# postback to one record in drop down list, not to all records

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

i use with `asp.net` 
I have a `DropDownList` with more than 10000 records. 
I have a button that post the selected record and save it in DataBase. 
The problem: I press the button it does postback to all page, It takes a long time, because it returns all the records to server (more than 10000)

How can I get to do postback Only the selected record and not all records?( i can use jquery)

Comment: show us your code. what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

For Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpRelocatedCountry" runat="server" onchange="Javascript:return Setstate(this);">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnbindstate" runat="server" OnClick="btnbindstate_Click" style="display:none;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function Setstate(ele) {
 var selectedvalue = "";
 selectedvalue = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;
 if (selectedvalue == 38 || selectedvalue == 239) {//38=Canada & 239=USA (Your options)
  document.getElementById('<%=btnbindstate.ClientID%>').click();
 }
}
</script>
```

Now Your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` code will be on `OnClick` event of button.